# copy data from USERNAME to WHITELIST with active record

Tags: php, database, activerecord

its a account activation script. It change table value ACTIVE from 0 to 1 but i need also put USERNAME values in whitelist after account activation

```
else if(isset($_GET["user"])){
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'validate'){
        $individual = $queries->getWhere("users", array("id", "=", $_GET["user"]));
        if($individual[0]->active == 0){


            $whitelist = 

            $queries->update('users', $_GET['user'], array(
                'active' => 1,
                'whitelist' => $whitelist
            ));
            echo '<script data-cfasync="false">window.location.replace(\'/admin/users/?user=' . $_GET['user'] . '\')</script>';
            die();
        } else {
            // already active
            echo '<script data-cfasync="false">window.location.replace(\'/admin/users/?user=' . $_GET['user'] . '\')</script>';
            die();
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? As well, if you have `die();` on both conditions of your `if`, you can just add it after the `if` is done since it is not in fact conditional.

Comment: all is working good but i need   copy USERNAME values in WHITELIST after account activation

Comment: If you are already running the validation check (`$_GET['action'] == 'validate')`) then you can just use `$_GET["user"]`.

Comment: $queries->update('users', $_GET['user'], array(
                            'active' => 1,
                            'whitelist' => "username from db"
                        )); how i can do it? username from table must duplicate in table whitelist afrer activation

Comment: Just do another query that updates `whitelist` table.